# Transclude in Angular directive putting elements inside a single 'span'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive:

```
myapp.directive('envtable',  function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<table class="table" ng-transclude></table>'
};
});
```

This is how i use it in html (using bootstrap css)

```
<envtable>
    <tr>
      <td>OS</td>
      <td>{{env.osName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>OS Version</td>
      <td>{{env.osVersion}}</td>
    </tr>
  </envtable>
```

However, the code generated looks like this in chrome:

```
<table class="table" ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-scope ng-binding">

      OS
      Windows 8


      OS Version
      6.2

  </span></table>
```

As you can see, Angular just ignored all my `tr/td` tags and put the contents in a single span element. Why is this happening?

Btw, as an experiment, i tried using just a transcluded `p` tag in the envtable instead of the `tr\td` tags and in that case angular just adds a `ng-scope` class to the `p` tag. So why does it screw up these tr/td tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this works with `restrict: 'A'`

```
<table envtable>
    <tr>
        <td>OS</td>
        <td>{{env.osName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>OS Version</td>
        <td>{{env.osVersion}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jMWp/)**</kbd>

Comment: it does. but apparently only if the element the attribute is added to is a 'table', not a 'div'. Any idea why?

Comment: @pdeva the table directive is a bit special since it needs to generate all `tbody` stuff, maybe the generation messes up with the inner tr and td

Answer (score 1):

Just provide another example in case your table template has other elements like thead

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJtYbY?p=preview)

```
app.directive('envtable', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<table class="NewTable"><thead><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></thead></table>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
      var item = transcludeFn(scope, function(clone) {
        return clone.children();
      });
      elem.append(item);
    }
  };
});


 <table envtable>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='r in rows'>
        <td>{{r.col1}}</td>
        <td>{{r.col2}}</td>
        <td>{{r.col3}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a repeat but your solution is simple. Avoid using `<table>`!

If you remove the `<table>` tags, replace them with `<div>`'s with `display: table` styling it should work just fine.

Comment: but why exactly does using Table cause an issue?

Comment: See this issue posted on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted, Roy has the right answer here. If you try to transclude inside a <table> the browser and angular do not know how to handle the data. So the official work around by the people developing on angular is turn them into <div>'s with display: table