# ng-transclude doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm experimenting with directives. Why does the ng-transclude in the jsfiddle below contain the span element and not just the content of the original span? I thought it should just include the span tag itself if I set transclude: 'element'.

http://jsfiddle.net/tidelipop/DzVQ9/

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [], function($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.directive("inlineEdit", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            template: "<textarea ng-transclude></textarea>",
            scope: true,
            controller: function($scope){
                toggleEditMode = function(){
                    $scope.editMode = !$scope.editMode;
                }
            }
        };
    });
})
```

Comment: Isn't that related to this bug on angular : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1293 ? It creates a span element around the transcluded content, which seems to be your issue

Comment: Sure seems like it! ..but shouldn't that problem already be solved?

Comment: it seems to be linked with IE compatibility, there was a post here from Misko Hevery that explained it https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/angular/2rPL2lqdCho/QU37wXUPyxoJ it's from 1 year ago, but it seems they couldn't find a solution, the part of code responsible for that is still there : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L466.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transclude in Angular directive putting elements inside a single 'span'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156930/transclude-in-angular-directive-putting-elements-inside-a-single-span)