# Angular directive to replace table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a special rule for directive that handles `<table>`?

I don't know why I'm not able to create a directive that will replace `<table>`.

I created a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/o43yyupa/2/);

I was looking in Angular issues, but don't found the answer.
[This discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459#issuecomment-67235182) is interesting.

**Edit**

*Why do you want replace table?*

The real template is more complex, like:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div no-result-message="items"></div>
  <table ng-transclude></table>
  <div paging="items"></div>
</div>
```

Also, I want to move the `ng-repeat` inside this directive instead of in `tr` direct;

Comment: Why do you want *replace table*?

Comment: This is a small part of a group of directives.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156930/transclude-in-angular-directive-putting-elements-inside-a-single-span) you might have better luck if you use `restrict: 'A'` in your directive definition. Although I'm not sure it will replace the table, but I can't think why you would want to do that. Furthermore I'm pretty sure the ability to replace elements in directives is deprecated in angular or will be in the next release.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o43yyupa/4/)

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        {first: 'Foo', last: 'Bar'},
        {first: 'Baz', last: 'Zox'},
    ];
})
.directive('grid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<table ng-transclude></table>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Is this a bug or what else?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I've never had reason to manipulate the table element in such a way.